# How to restrict the selectable date ranges in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I need to use datepicker which provides me the option of restricting the selectable dates. We had been using jQuery UI which is used to support it using minDate, maxDate options.

```
$("#id_date").datepicker({minDate: +1, maxDate: '+1M +10D'});
```

Recently we started using Twitter Bootstrap for our styles. And apparently, Twitter Bootstrap is incompatible with jQuery UI styles. So I tried using one of the bootstrap compatible datepickers available at http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/.

Unfortunately, the above plugin is not as configurable as jQuery UI's datepicker. Can anyone help me out with restricting the selectable date ranges in the new datepicker.

Comment: if jQuery datepicker works except for styles, it might be easier to turn those styles off than to add non-existant functionality to a different library. Take a look at the 'Theming' tab on http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396540/7772054) answer will help you.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The Bootstrap datepicker is able to set date-range. But it is not available in the initial release/Master Branch. Check the branch as 'range' there (or just see at https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), you can do it simply with startDate and endDate.

Example:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-2m',
    endDate: '+2d'
});
```

Comment: @NandhakumarSri Here you go - https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker. There were a few changes in the tree structure of the repository due to which the answer link didn't work.

Comment: what is this `'-2m'` and `+2d` all about

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Just in case.. should be months(m) and days(d); ie, a valid date is 2 months prior to today through 2 days past today

Answer (score 46):

With selectable date ranges you might want to use something like this. My solution prevents selecting #from_date  bigger than #to_date and changes #to_date startDate every time when user selects new date in #from_date box:

http://bootply.com/74352

JS file:

```
var startDate = new Date('01/01/2012');
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();

ToEndDate.setDate(ToEndDate.getDate()+365);

$('.from_date').datepicker({

    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '01/01/2012',
    endDate: FromEndDate, 
    autoclose: true
})
    .on('changeDate', function(selected){
        startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    }); 
$('.to_date')
    .datepicker({

        weekStart: 1,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: ToEndDate,
        autoclose: true
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(selected){
        FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input class="from_date" placeholder="Select start date" contenteditable="false" type="text">
<input class="to_date" placeholder="Select end date" contenteditable="false" type="text"
```

And do not forget to include bootstrap datepicker.js and .css files aswell.

Answer (score 40):

The example above can be simplify a bit. Additionally you can put date manually from keyboard instead of selecting it via datepicker only. When clearing the value you need to handle also *'on clearDate'* action to remove startDate/endDate boundary:

JS file:

```js
$(".from_date").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
}).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
    $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
});

$(".to_date").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var endDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
}).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
    $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', null);
});
```

HTML:

```html
<input class="from_date" placeholder="Select start date" type="text" name="from_date">
<input class="to_date" placeholder="Select end date" type="text" name="to_date">
```

Comment: It works!!! Just note that the .valueOf() didn't work for me, because datepicker check for a date in the setStartDate.

Comment: It's 2020 and your code still working! By the way how to add 1 day into the `.to_date` ???

Answer (score 14):

Most answers and explanations are not to explain what is a valid string of `endDate` or `startDate`.
Danny gave us two useful example.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-2m',
    endDate: '+2d'
});
```

But why?let's take a look at the source code at `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`.
There are some code begin line 1343 tell us how does it work.

```
if (/^[-+]\d+[dmwy]([\s,]+[-+]\d+[dmwy])*$/.test(date)) {
            var part_re = /([-+]\d+)([dmwy])/,
                parts = date.match(/([-+]\d+)([dmwy])/g),
                part, dir;
            date = new Date();
            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                part = part_re.exec(parts[i]);
                dir = parseInt(part[1]);
                switch (part[2]) {
                    case 'd':
                        date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + dir);
                        break;
                    case 'm':
                        date = Datetimepicker.prototype.moveMonth.call(Datetimepicker.prototype, date, dir);
                        break;
                    case 'w':
                        date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + dir * 7);
                        break;
                    case 'y':
                        date = Datetimepicker.prototype.moveYear.call(Datetimepicker.prototype, date, dir);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return UTCDate(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds(), 0);
        }
```

There are four kinds of expressions.

- `w` means week
- `m` means month
- `y` means year
- `d` means day

Look at the regular expression `^[-+]\d+[dmwy]([\s,]+[-+]\d+[dmwy])*$`.
You can do more than these `-0d` or `+1m`.

Try harder like `startDate:'+1y,-2m,+0d,-1w'`.And the separator `,` could be one of `[\f\n\r\t\v,]`

Comment: This is right and perfect answer. Accepted answer might have resolved questioner's issue but giving more description about solution will add value in it.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use the options with `data` attributes, like this(minimum date 1 week before):

```
<input class='datepicker' data-date-start-date="-1w">
```

More info: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

Answer (score 0):

i am using v3.1.3 and i had to use `data('DateTimePicker')` like this

```
var fromE = $( "#" + fromInput );
var toE = $( "#" + toInput );
$('.form-datepicker').datetimepicker(dtOpts);

$('.form-datepicker').on('change', function(e){
   var isTo = $(this).attr('name') === 'to';

   $( "#" + ( isTo ? fromInput : toInput  ) )
      .data('DateTimePicker')[ isTo ? 'setMaxDate' : 'setMinDate' ](moment($(this).val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready( function() {
$("#submitdate").datepicker( {
minDate: 0,
maxDate: 0,

```
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help