# How to disable future dates in bootstrap using datepicker function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    endDate: Date.today()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **numberOfMonths**

or you can read http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: It s bootstrap datepicker in which use endDate to disable future dates but it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933173/how-to-restrict-the-selectable-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

The Idea behind to disable future dates from current month is, to get current  month dates and set it as end date.

```
$(function(){
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0); 
$('.datepicker').datepicker({format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',  startDate : new Date(), autoclose: true,endDate: lastDate});
})
```