# How to disable future two dates after current date in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker for delivery date. But I want to disable two dates after current date so that it will atleast take two days to prepare product after placing an order.

Comment: can you add code of your try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict the selectable date ranges in Bootstrap Datepicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933173/how-to-restrict-the-selectable-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with the [`beforeShowDay`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.4/options.html#beforeshowday) callback.

```
var today = new Date();
var deliveryThreshold = new Date();
deliveryThreshold.setDate(deliveryThreshold.getDate() + 2);

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    //..
    startDate: '+1d',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (date >= today && date <= deliveryThreshold) {
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/205/

Comment: Thanks. I did it with startDate:'+1'.

Comment: Please at least mark the answer as accepted as this solves the problem in your question. Thanks!