# How to set 3 months date range from current date in date picker?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I want to enable only 3 months from current date in [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
function addThreeMonthsToStartDate(today) {
    var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+3, getDate());
    return lastDate;
}

$("#startdate").datepicker({
    isDisabled: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < Date.now() ? false : true;
    },
    autoClose: true,
    viewStart: 0,
    weekStart: 1,
    maxDate: lastDate,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Only set the maxDate attribute with your criteria.

Comment: Here is a whole topic about your problem.
Already on Stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933173/how-to-restrict-the-selectable-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I got the solution as below:

```
    $("#startdate").datepicker({
    isDisabled: function(date) {
        var d = new Date(); 
        return date.valueOf() < d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+3) ? false : true;
    },
    autoClose: true,
    viewStart: 0,
    weekStart: 1,
    maxDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to your problem** it allows only 3 months from current date.

```
 $('#startdate').datepicker({
        maxDate: "+90d",
        minDate:0
    });
```

Comment: This is 90 days not 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function addThreeMonthsToStartDate(today) {
 // var today = new Date();
    var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+3, 
                   today.getDate());
    }



$("#startdate").datepicker({
    isDisabled: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < Date.now() ? false : true;
    },
    minDate: "dateToday", // If you need to disable past dates
    autoClose: true,
    viewStart: 0,
    weekStart: 1,
    maxDate: lastDate,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you most use **startDate** and **endDate** in bootstrap datepicker

```
 function addThreeMonthsToStartDate(today) {
 // var today = new Date();
    var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+3, 
                   today.getDate());
    }



$("#startdate").datepicker({
    isDisabled: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < Date.now() ? false : true;
    },
    startDate: "dateToday", // If you need to disable past dates
    autoClose: true,
    viewStart: 0,
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: lastDate,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```